# Drawing a curve through a set of N points, where N>2

Tags: javascript, points, bezier, spline

I need to draw a curve smoothly through N points with N>2 with Javascript. I am currently using the bezierCurveTo() within an html5 canvas object. I've invested a good deal of time into trying to find the best method of accomplishing this, and while Catmull-Rom Splines sound promising, I am unaware of a way to draw them as lines. I therefore am left with Poly-line Bézier curves and need to find all intermediate control points.

It took me relearning a good deal of math but I have a **partially working example [here](http://dev.rngr.org/experiments/bezier-curves/)**. The line is not particularly smooth at times, and there is an issue with my control points being off for certain vectors. **[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51827/finding-two-bezier-control-points-given-three-points/) is my initial math.stackexchange question** that I asked to get the bulk of the math for the control points.

I would also be open to the Catmull-Rom Splines but would need some help as to how I can convert them to lines on the canvas. I have found [this](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/catmull-rom.html) resource, but again am lost in applying it to my needs.

Heres an image created from my example link above illustrating how to replicate the *bad* control points:

[image]

Thank you very much for any help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original code:

```
var a = new Array(points[p-1].x,points[p-1].y);
var b = new Array(points[p].x,points[p].y);
var c = new Array(points[p+1].x,points[p+1].y);

var delta_a = subtract_v(a, b);
var delta_c = subtract_v(c, b);

// Get vector (m) perpendicular bisector
var m = normalize_v( add_v( normalize_v(delta_a),normalize_v(delta_c) ) );

// Get ma and mc
var ma = normalize_v( subtract_v(delta_a,multiply_v(multiply_v(delta_a,m),m) ) );
var mc = normalize_v( subtract_v(delta_c,multiply_v(multiply_v(delta_c,m),m) ) );

// Get the coordinates
points[p].c2x = resolution( b[0] + ( (Math.sqrt( sqr(delta_a[0]) + sqr(delta_a[1]) ) / tightness) * ma[0] ) );
points[p].c2y = resolution( b[1] + ( (Math.sqrt( sqr(delta_a[0]) + sqr(delta_a[1]) ) / tightness) * ma[1] ) );
points[p+1].c1x = resolution( b[0] + ( (Math.sqrt( sqr(delta_c[0]) + sqr(delta_c[1]) ) / tightness) * mc[0] ) );
points[p+1].c1y = resolution( b[1] + ( (Math.sqrt( sqr(delta_c[0]) + sqr(delta_c[1]) ) / tightness) * mc[1] ) );
```

I have no idea what "Get ma and mc" is supposed to do here. What you need is a vector orthogonal to the angle bisector (`m`), and its negative.

[image: Sorry for the horrible drawing]

So this should be fine:

```
var delta_a = subtract_v(b, a); // note that we're calculating AB instead of BA
var delta_c = subtract_v(c, b);

// Get an orthogonal to the angle bisector
var m = normalize_v( add_v( normalize_v(delta_a),normalize_v(delta_c) ) );

var ma = [-m[0],-m[1]];
var mc = m;
```

Also make sure to remove the `resolution()` for your control points.

**Edit:**
You should also add a fallback for edge cases (for example, `A==B` or `A==C`, in which case your script will throw an exception, trying to normalize the 0 vector)

Comment: Sweet mother of pearl, thank you so much! It all works perfectly now. I have been struggling with this for a week... wanting to understand it rather than just ask for a solution. I have no idea what `ma` and `mc` were, I just got it from the math.stackexchange answer... but your solution is far more simple... and actually works! All the best! (And yes, I will remove `resolution()` from the CPs... was just trying to see coordinates more clearly while debugging)